# Are there still those who obey the mitzvah of Ma'aser Behemah?

Tags: halacha, animals, maaser-tithes

If I am a farmer or keep animals, is it possible to obey the mitzvah of Ma'aser Behemah in today's times? Is is right to obey this mitzvah?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Moshe.  If you add in to the question why you think it should or shouldn't be (your motivation for asking), you can expect better answers. Click the little edit button below the question to edit it.

Answer (score 8):

The Mitzva applies in all places and at all times, even today and even outside of Israel. (Bechorot 9:1)

However, since nowadays we can't offer the animals as Korbanot and we'd have to wait for the animal to get a blemish in order to eat it, there was a rabbinic enactment not to fulfill the Mitzva lest people come to sin by eating it before it got a blemish. (Rambam Bechorot 6:2)

Hence, it is possible to obey this Mitzva but it is not right to do so nowadays.

Comment: יש כח ביד חכמים וכו'?

Comment: @Yitzchak Shev Ve'Al Taaseh presumably. There is no issue of Tevel so there is no other consequences of it.

Comment: What if the baby animals are all baalei mumim?

Comment: @Heshy not just if, you could do it on purpose https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Firstlings.6.9 The fact that chazal didn't enact that solution implies they were still concerned it would also lead to mistakes